# Syntax error for mysql while doing inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

```
 SELECT t1.Type,
    FROM PERFORMS_SURGERY AS PS
    INNER JOIN
 (SELECT CPT, Type FROM SURGERY) as t1
ON t1.CPT = PS.CPT
    WHERE PS.PUsername = "klove30"
```

I get a syntax error at "FROM PERFORMS_SURGERY AS PS
        INNER JOIN
(SELECT CPT, Type FROM SURGERY)". What is the syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.Type,
    FROM ...
```

You should not have a comma after the last column in the select-list.

Change it to be like this:

```
SELECT t1.Type
    FROM ...
```

Comment: I'm retarded. Thanks. Will accept when it lets me (in 12 minutes).

Comment: don't worry about it, commas are easy to miss in SQL.